# General equivalence between closed set and accumulation points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Studying analysis we were given the definition of closed set and accumulation points.

We than proved that given a metric space $(X,d)$, given $A \subseteq X$, $A$ is closed iff $A' \subseteq A$. I was wondering how can $A'$ be a subset and not always equal to $A$, so I did some research and for $\mathbb{R}$ they are in fact equal. Does this extends to arbitrary sets and metrics? If not could you provide some examples where this fails?

Comment: If $A$ is finite does it has any accumulation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, $\{1\}'=\emptyset$ and $[0,1] \cup \{2\} = [0,1]$ so it *can* be a subset of $A$.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense, I can see it now. Thanks